# Implementing Pushwoosh on new Google Console

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

I am trying to implement Pushwoosh. I have implemented it before and on google console we create a API key ->"Server Key"
but now when i go to the console i am not able to find the option to create the Server key for pushwooosh. When i directly create a Api Key it shows error in pushwoosh.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Dashboard: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard

Then hit "Credentials". Then select and create API Key there.
Make sure the project matches the Project Number in the app.

Comment: We used to create Server key, but after the implementation of firebase the process has change